# Can't Install expo-cli using npm in ubuntu operating system?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, native

```
$ sudo npm install -g expo-cli
[sudo] password for maky: 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.13.1 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.13.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...G20jDnNTkEHGTUpd\n3Yv'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-09T08_40_53_546Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tried to clean cache with `npm cache clean --force`?

Comment: Yes, Still not working...

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing with Yarn `yarn global add expo-cli` Please make sure you have installed yarn. You can check if yarn is installed by `yarn --version`.

Comment: success Installed "expo-cli@3.20.3" with binaries, But Can't access the expo using terminal can you help me in that ?

Answer (score 0):

i've already installed expo with yarn but when i try to create a project using expo i got this output:

```
$ expo init gg
```

Command 'expo' not found, did you mean:
command 'expr' from deb coreutils (8.32-3ubuntu1)
command 'expn' from deb sendmail-base (8.15.2-20)
Try: sudo apt install